# php how to convert umlaut German vowels from ä to ae, ö to oe, ü to ue, ß to ss

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP class which exploits this API:
http://www.voicerss.org/api/documentation.aspx

I'd like a user could write some text in the textarea, then select the right language, of course, and then he can hear the right pronunciation of all.

The problem I've got, is a well-known one, I could say, the UTF-8 converting characters issue;  that's how to replace the umlaut German vowels ä with ae, ö with oe, and also ß with ss etc.

The same problem with my native language, Italian: I mean the accented letters ò, è, é, à, ù etc.
In Spanish the same with the ñ and so on for all the supported languages of the mentioned API.

I don't want to REMOVE the ä with a for instance, as if you speak German, you'll know that the pronunciation of a word with ä is exactly ae: for example geändert gets the phonetic pronunciation
of geaendert and not geandert!.

I tried hard so many times searching this site all over, and also the web but still I got no solution to my problem.

Here is my class:

```
 <?php
 class TexttoSpeech
{
    public $api = 'http://api.voicerss.org/?key=611e0eb0f671415788150de40f609bdd&src={TEXT}&hl={LANGUAGE}&r={SPEECH_RATE}&f={AUDIO_FORMAT}';

public $response;

/**
 * Save the MP3 file in the folder called "audio" 
 * with the .mp3 extension 
 */
public $audioDir;

/**
 * The speech rate (speed). Allows values: from -10 (slowest speed) up to 10 
 * (fastest speed). 
 * Default value: 0 (normal speed). (optional) 
 */
public $r = '-2';

/**
 * The speech audio formats. Allows values: see Audio Formats.
 * Default value: 8khz_8bit_mono. (optional) 
 */
public $f = '48khz_16bit_stereo'; 

public function __construct($text, $language)
    {
        // search for the 2 values I need to change in the main API
        $needle = array('{TEXT}', '{LANGUAGE}', '{SPEECH_RATE}', '{AUDIO_FORMAT}');

        $replace = array($text, $language, $this->r, $this->f);

        // the main API
        $api = str_replace($needle, $replace, $this->api);

        $this->response = $this->get($api);

        $this->audioDir = 'audio/' . $text . '.mp3';
    }

public function get($api) 
    {
        if ( function_exists('curl_init') ) 
            {       
                // use cURL to fetch data
                $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                // execute
                $response = curl_exec($ch);

                // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
                curl_close ($ch);
            } 
        else if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) 
            {
                // fall back to fopen()
                $response = file_get_contents($api, 'r');
            }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Of course here, I'm still in local and I've already controlled  I have a full list of locales installed with the shell:
locale -a

and also with the PHP dedicated function:

```
<?php
  system('locale -a')
 ?>
```

here it is ( I'm trying with the German, now):
As someone said in the PHP official web manual, I tried to use *first* the setlocale() function and *then* the iconv() for German, of course, but I get the errror:

Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in etc..

when I write, for instance, in the textarea:

**Etwas ist geändert jetzt.**
The **ä** creates the problem!.
This is way I instance my class, creating the object, I called **$t2s**.

```
<form action="<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
<ol>
    <li>
        <select name="language" style="width: 200px" class="">
            <option value="">------- Select language -------</option>
            <option value="ca-es">Catalan</option>
            <option value="zh-cn">Chinese (China)</option>
            <option value="zh-hk">Chinese (Hong Kong)</option>
            <option value="zh-tw">Chinese (Taiwan)</option>
            <option value="da-dk">Danish</option>
            <option value="nl-nl">Dutch</option>
            <option value="en-au">English (Australia)</option>
            <option value="en-ca">English (Canada)</option>
            <option value="en-gb">English (Great Britain)</option>
            <option value="en-in">English (India)</option>
            <option value="en-us">English (United States)</option>
            <option value="fi-fi">Finnish</option>
            <option value="fr-ca">French (Canada)</option>
            <option value="fr-fr">French (France)</option>
            <option value="de-de">German</option>
            <option value="it-it">Italian</option>
            <option value="ja-jp">Japanese</option>
            <option value="ko-kr">Korean</option>
            <option value="nb-no">Norwegian</option>
            <option value="pl-pl">Polish</option>
            <option value="pt-br">Portuguese (Brazil)</option>
            <option value="pt-pt">Portuguese (Portugal)</option>
            <option value="ru-ru">Russian</option>
            <option value="es-mx">Spanish (Mexico)</option>
            <option value="es-es">Spanish (Spain)</option>
            <option value="sv-se">Swedish (Sweden)</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>        
        <label for="text">Write your text here</label>
            <textarea name="text" id="text" rows="6" style="width: 600px" class="" ></textarea>
    </li>
</ol>

<p>     
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert" />
</p>
```

```
 <?php
   include_once 'TexttoSpeech.class.php';

   if ( isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['text']) &&
     isset($_POST['language']) )

   {    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');

    // Remove all characters except letters, numbers and spaces
    $text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $_POST['text']);

    $text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);   

    // The spaces in the sentence are replaced with the Plus symbol
    $text = urlencode($text);       

    $t2s = new TexttoSpeech($text, $_POST['language']);

    file_put_contents($t2s->audioDir, $t2s->response);

    echo '
            <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
            <source src="' . $t2s->audioDir . '" type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
            <br />
            Saved mp3 location :  ' . $t2s->audioDir . '
            <br />
          '
        ;
     }
  ?>
```

Hope somebody can help me!.
Thanks.

Comment: You may check `ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` to see what result you will get. Also maybe umlaut is wrongly processed by your `preg_replace` pattern (had this sort of trouble with cyrillic, by default it is not unicode), can you check that the string is ok after `preg_replace`

Comment: I tried to set ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE and if I write for ex. geändert I get a .mp3 file called gendert.mp3. I mean I get a kinda French pronunciation instead of the right geaendert German one!.  If I don't use the setlocale() and iconv() functions at all, I get exactly the same result, which let me think the problem is in the preg_replace() function. But how can I resolve that? Thanks.

Comment: I think that is because your `preg_replace()` pattern is not utf-8 compatible, so as umlauts are two bytes and other characters are one it may eat part of umlaut. You may add `/u` to treat as strings utf-8 http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php or modify the pattern to include all the characters you want http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php (something like `\p{L}`)

Comment: I tried also to use setlocale() then iconv() the way you suggested here above,  and then preg_replace() but I get Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in .....etc. Maybe as I said, it's a problem with the regex here. I really have no clue how to resolve it, as the same issue happens with the Italian accented letters, and it's impossible to write a right regex for all the languages supported by the API here. What a mess! Can't see an easy way out, at all!.

Comment: I cancelled the setlocale() e the iconv() functions and tried to change the  regex as you said here, with the addition of /u. This way: $text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s/u]/', '', $_POST['text']); but I get  Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ']' in ....etc.  How should I use it then? Thanks

Comment: Try `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/u'` pattern. But I think you will have to replace `a-zA-Z0-9` with more aware of different characters pattern anyway. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767056/php-regex-for-multiple-unicode-characters

Comment: I tried your solution but I got an empty mp3 file. gonna look at your link later, it's strange anyway nobody has already given a solution in the PHP manual website: I mean the admins give no examples for the complete support of languages widely used as German for example. Ok it's not English but here in Europe it's one of the most important, I'd say.

Comment: I tried different regex following your link here above, still I have got no result at all! No further help?

Comment: The correct preg pattern to match letters, numbers and space will be `/[^\pL\pN\s]/u` . Howewer I do not know if it will match chinese and similar languages. But iconv on the string you provided (Etwas ist geändert jetzt.) gives me `Etwas ist ge"andert jetzt` which is not what you want. Perhaps that is because I'm on windows and did not set locale correctly so you need to check it in your environment.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I found the problem could be easily solved if only the API could accept the use of iconv(). Here in local with Xampp on my Linux distro, if I write this code: <?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');

$text = 'geändert';

$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);

$text = urlencode($text);

echo $text;
?>
I  get the right result:  geaendert. It's a problem with their servers that don't accept the use of this function, as somebody said here: [link]http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Follow the link above and have a look at what a user called Jorotega says here. He explains that "Problem is that configuration is dependent of the sysadmin of the machine where you're hosted, so iconv is pretty much useless by default,  depending on what configuration is used by your distro or the machine's admin."

Comment: If `iconv()` with `ASCII//TRANSLIT` doesn't work for you with German umlauts (ä/ö/ü => ae/oe/ue, despite setting `setlocale()` to a German utf8 locale, [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412085/how-to-make-textslug-convert-german-umlauts-properly#answer-50415750) was the solution for me, using [`transliterator_transliterate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) with `de-ASCII` supplied via the transliterator build string.