# How to make Text::slug() convert german umlauts properly?

Tags: cakephp, diacritics, slug, cakephp-3.x

I am using CakePHP 3.6, and when I am using words with german umlauts like:

```
Text::slug('Grundstücke')
```

I will get:

> Grundstucke (where ü = u)

but that's not correct, I should get:

> Grundstuecke (where ü = ue)

Is there an option to set so that umlauts are being converted the way I want them to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Change your transliterator

The `Text::slug()` uses internally `transliterator_transliterate` (see [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php)).

So you need to change the default transliterator that is being used.

After some research I found one that will work for you.

At the end of your bootstrap.php file add:

```
\Cake\Utility\Text::setTransliteratorId( 'de-ASCII; Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove ');
```

Then your text will be converted as you expect.

#### Notes

Resources I've used to find this answer:

- [CakekPHP `Text::transliterate()`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/text.html#convert-strings-into-ascii)
- [Transliteration Identifiers Documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Transliterator-Identifiers)
- [transliterator_list_ids](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.listids.php) - to get a list of valid identifiers - this is how I found the one that finally worked: `de-ASCII`
- [Text Utility API](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Utility.Text.html#_setTransliteratorId) - to set the a new default transliterator id.

Comment: It should be noted that `de-ASCII` is only [**available as of ICU 60.1**](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/browser/tags/release-60-1/icu4c/source/data/translit/de_ASCII.txt). In earlier versions one would have to supply rules manually AFAIR.

Comment: it looks like, I have no luck with this solution... do you mind, having a closer chat about this? Can I contact you?

Comment: quite busy these days. if this is not working for you it is likely that as ndm said above you need a newer version of the transliteration module. maybe upgrade your PHP version to the latest?

Comment: ICU moved to GitHub/JIRA, the link I've posted above isn't valid anymore, [**look here**](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/release-60-1/icu4c/source/data/translit/de_ASCII.txt) instead.

Comment: I would like to upvote this a thousand times! I'm not even working with cakephp, but trying to transliterate German umlauts correctly with standard PHP. `iconv()` with `ASCII//TRANSLIT` wouldn't work, despite setting `setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf-8")` as recommended everywhere (and yes, that locale is available on the system). I had been searching for hours (literally!) until I found this.